# Transform a Linux command to windows (mysql)

Tags: mysql, linux, windows, cmd

I am doing a tutorial to install and use a database almost all the commands are in mysql command line, but one of steps is using a Linux command. The problem is that i am in windows 7 is there any way of running this command `zcat ptwiki-latest-category.sql.gz | mysql wikipedia -u wikipedia --password=saskia` but in windows. I am using MySQL server 5.1.32.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log into mysql,

```
mysql wikipedia -u wikipedia --password=saskia
```

and then open your SQL file, `ptwiki-latest-category.sql.gz`, and paste the queries there into your command line to run them. Or you can unzip the file and run

```
source ptwiki-latest-category.sql
```

at the mysql prompt if the commands are too big.

Comment: The commands are enormous and don't fit on the console but thanks

Comment: For that to work the sql file need to be in the same folder as the db?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have zcat command in windows shell. Pipe is working on both windows and linux, so you only need zcat. It can be found in GNU utils collection for windows, for example MSYS Projects. Look at http://www.mingw.org/ after default installation you will get zcat in c:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\

Comment: Ty i am going to try it